# Conectar un objeto JTable con un objeto Collection

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un método `public Collection<Suppliers> getAllSuppliers()` el cual obviamente retorna los datos de la tabla `suppliers`.

En la parte cliente `swing` intento mostrar en un `JFrame` un objeto `JTable` conteniendo los registro de la tabla.

```
Runnable runner = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Facade facade = new Facade();
            Collection<Suppliers> suppliers = facade.getAllSuppliers();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Data");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300, 600);

            Container content = frame.getContentPane();
            content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
```

Estoy iniciando en el tema de aplicaciones swing el modelo `MVC`, estoy intentando pasar el objeto `suppliers` el cual contiene un colección de `suppliers` al `DefaultTableModel` pero sin éxito. ¿Tengo que cambiar la `interface Collection`?

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Si pusieras el código de `Suppliers`, los datos que quieres mostrar en la tabla y el orden, sería más fácil darte una solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que pides tienes que utilizar un `TableModel` para cargar los datos y pasárselo a tu `JTable`. Te recomiendo usar un [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) con su constructor `DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)`.

Te dejo el ejemplo más básico que he hecho para que veas la conexión con la información que nos has dado.
1.- Vamos a cargar los datos y los nombre de las columnas para crear el modelo con ellos:

```
Object[] columnas = new Object[]{"Descripción Supplier"};
Object[][] datos = new Object[suppliers.size()][columnas.length];

Iterator iterator = suppliers.iterator();

for(int i = 0; i < suppliers.size(); i++){
    datos[i][0] = iterator.next();
}
```

2.- Con los datos cargados, instanciamos el `TableModel`:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(datos, columnas);
```

3.- Finalmente hay que presentarlos. Lo más rápido un mensaje emergente para verlo:

```
JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(new JTable(model));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "EJEMPLO SUPPLIERS", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Si hubieras puesto más información podría haberse ajustado más a lo que necesites. Ahora mismo tus objetos `Suppliers` se cargan enteros en una sola columna. `DefaultTableModel` por defecto renderiza la celda como `String` por lo que llamará al método `toString()` para rellenar la celda.

Si cargas el argumento `data` con los distintos atributos éstos aparecerán según el orden de carga debajo de cada columna que has declarado en el objeto `columna` en el mismo orden.
Como puede haber datos muy distintos se usa `Object` que es genérico, pero puedes crear [reders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) para cada celda para que muestre lo que quieres.

Algunos lenguajes de programación parece que dan más facilidades de "conectar" datos como dices, pero la potencia de Java haciéndolo de esta manera no tiene límites.