# ¿Cómo obtener correctamente un entero usando ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero llenar las filas de un `JTable` y he usado:

```
String [] registros = new String[6];
```

En mi caso la primera columna de mi tabla es "id_usuario" de tipo `int`, el cual es PK, NN y AI.

Ya que mi variable "registros" es de tipo String, he hecho esto usando `ResultSet`:

```
registros[0] = rs.getString("id_usuario");
```

No sé si es la forma correcta, aunque no recibo ningún error. ¿Debería convertir `int` a `String` o no?.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta para este caso?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sabes que ese campo es un `int` en vez de usar lo que has puesto debes usar:

```
registros[0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
```

Ese método te devuelve ya el entero.

En tu caso te dará error porque `registros` es un arreglo de `String`. Te recomiendo que lo cambies a `Object[]` e incluso si estás haciendo ya la carga de los datos que quieres mostrar lo hagas `Object[][]` pues eso o un vector es lo que vas a necesitar para hacer tu `TableModel` para instanciar tu `JTable`.

Ayer justo respondí [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36615/conectar-un-objeto-jtable-con-un-objeto-collection/36619#36619) hablando de esto mismo que te puede servir de guía para tu siguiente paso.

Por otra parte, puedes ver mas métodos que se adaptan a los distintos valores que puedes esperar de un campo en la [documentación de ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Como en tu base de datos tienes distintos tipos de datos, un arreglo de `Object` te va a permitir cargar todo, incluso objetos que hayas creado encapsulando toda la información de un usuario por ejemplo, y luego ya creas el render que necesites en cada celda.

Comment: Object, la unica diferencia es que puedo ingresarle datos de cualquer tipo?, int, string, double?... es mas eficiente que un String []?

Comment: Se puede como te he dicho: en vez de usar `String[] registros` usa `Object[] registros` y podrás meter cualquier valor. Luego te va a hacer falta pasarlo a `Object` igualmente para hacer tu `TableModel`.

Comment: una ultima pregunta, espero no sea molestia, como podría usar Object[][] si no se la cantidad de registros que habrán para las filas?.

Comment: Sí que sabes la cantidad de registros. Si haces `resultSet.last()` te posicionas en la última fila y luego haces `resultSet.getRow()` te dice el número de la actual (la última). Luego vuelves a empezar con `resultSet.first()`. No obstante si prefieres puedes usar la instanciación con `Vector` y puedes ir iterando el `ResultSet` mientras cargas cada fila del vector de datos con `datos.add(Object)`.

Comment: esa opción suena muy complicado, nunca he hecho algo así, aún estoy en etapa de aprendizaje, no entendí mucho esta opción. :(

Comment: En vez de instanciar la TableModel con `new DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)` instancias con `new DefaultTableModel(Vector data, Vector columnNames)` y vas cargando las filas en el vector `data`. Si ves la [documentación de DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel(java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector)) y lo intentas verás que te va saliendo sólo. Si tienes problemas abre otra pregunta para no mezclarlas y alargar los comentarios demasiado.

Comment: que tal esta forma que he encontrado: http://oi68.tinypic.com/mjo70n.jpg

Comment: Es una opción más. Al final si te fijas es lo mismo. Yo prefiero de la otra forma porque normalmente tienes que tratar de alguna forma los datos para que quede mejor en vez de ir cargando cada dato bruto en cada celda. En ese caso iba a quedar muy farragoso porque no se vería bien todo el código de carga en una línea. Pero esto ya es una opinión, lo mejor es sentirse cómodo y que sea fácil de leer.

Comment: no me funcionó al final, sigo recibiendo el mismo error con cualquier forma que haga, debo de tener algun otro problema.

Comment: Abre otra pregunta con lo que hayas intentado y error

Comment: lo he hecho, gracias por el tip y toda tu ayuda, se agradece mucho.